# How to make a call to specific function in python script from command line

Tags: java, python

I have couple of questions regarding java to python integration

I have a python script and it has 2 or more functions.

1) How to make a call to specific function in python script from command line.

2) How to pass method parameters to one of the function in python script from command line

Comment: Why don't you just create a new script that calls the relevant function and use that script instead?

Comment: have you looked into using `python -c "import something;something(..)"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use argparse, like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser= argparse.ArgumentParser(description= 'test of parameters')
    parser.add_argument('-v', action= 'store_true', help= 'option one.')
    parser.add_argument('-p', dest= 'port', default=5, help= 'port number')
    parser.add_argument('command', default= None, nargs= '?', 
                   choices= ['auto', 'erase'], help= 'command to be executed')

    args= parser.parse_args()

    if args.command == 'auto':
        func1(args.port, args.v)

    elif args.command == 'erase':
        otherfunc(args.port)
```

check [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for all options available.

Then you call your code from command line:

```
mycode.py auto -p 12
```

or

```
mycode.py erase -v -p 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to skin the cat using argparse:

```
import argparse

def func1(param1):
    print 'inside func1'
    print param1

def func2(param2):
    print 'inside func2'
    print param2

def main(param):
    print 'inside main'
    func1(param)
    func2(param)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Perform some action.")

subparser = parser.add_subparsers(help="Run just one function.")

func1_parser = subparser.add_parser('func1', help="Run Function 1.")
func1_parser.add_argument('func1_param', type=func1,
                          help="Parameter for function 1")

func2_parser = subparser.add_parser('func2', help="Run Function 2.")
func2_parser.add_argument('func2_param', type=func2,
                          help='Parameter for Function 2')

main_parser = subparser.add_parser('main', help="Run the Main Function.")
main_parser.add_argument('param', type=main,
                         help="Run main function with value of -e.")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

This could be called from the command line like this:

```
bash-4.1$ ./test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] {func2,func1,main} ...

Perform some action.

positional arguments:
  {func2,func1,main}  Run just one function.
    func1             Run Function 1.
    func2             Run Function 2.
    main              Run the Main Function.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help          show this help message and exit

bash-4.1$ ./test.py main foo
inside main
inside func1
foo
inside func2
foo

bash-4.1$ ./test.py func1 foo
inside func1
foo

bash-4.1$ ./test.py func2 foo
inside func2
foo
```